# VueJS CORS error with Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nginx, woocommerce, vuejs2

I have a VueJS 2 app running on localhost with `vue-cli-service` and I am unable to query the Wordpress/Woocommerce REST API using axios without getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://woocommercewebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I can query other REST APIs just fine. But not Woocommerce.

I have Googled for 3 hours for a solution and tried these fixes, which do not work:

Apply CORS headers in Wordpress theme functions.php:

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Apply CORS headers in nginx virtual host config file:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS';
```

The header is there, I can see it in Postman but the error still appears.

I have tried all the Stackoverflow answers which do not work for me for some reason.

I have read about a proxy method, which does not suffice because I need to query multiple REST APIs from this app, not just one. And the server is not hosted on localhost, but a remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only way to solve this is by using a proxy on the localhost devserver.

The "solution" is in `vue.config.js` adding:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/woocommerce': {
        target: 'https://woocommercewebsite.com/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/woocommerce': ''
        }
      }
    },
...
```

And in axios query `https://localhost:8080/woocommerce/` which will route the request to the external server.

Why can I query other REST APIs on the internet from the same localhost app but not Woocommerce? Maybe someone can explain this.